# Why do padding and margin in iOS safari browser look different?

Tags: android, html, css, safari

In android or in windows everything looks perfect. Just on iphone devices in safari browser my website looks different. I have some padding and margin problem. How can I fix my problem?

This is my full code for media devices:

```css
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .container {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .gallery .thumbs {
        margin-top: 460px;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .left-column {
        max-width: 110%;
    }
    
    .right-column {
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .gallery .images>div.active { 
        height: 450px;
    }
    
    .gallery .images>span.right {
        margin-top:250px;
    }
    
    .gallery .images>span.left {
        margin-top:250px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 540px) {
    .left-column {
        width: 117%;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .gallery .thumbs {
        margin-top: 400px;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
   
    .gallery .images>div.active { 
        margin-top: -20px; 
        height: 400px; 
    }
}
```

This is on safari browser:

[image: This is on safari browser]

This is on android. On android looks perfect:

[image: This is on android. On android looks perfect]

Answer (score 0):

Because some html tags need the -webkit- prefix thingy in css that is used in safari or firefox, and so some of the css you have won't work on safari. https://w3schools.com has a lot css stuff that can help you.

add:

```
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
```

to your css

Comment: What are all those '>' for

Comment: I'm not sure where you need the prefixes, but that's just what came to mind.

Comment: .gallery .images>span.right
Selects all span.right elements where the parent is a .gallery .images element

Comment: is there a way that I can see what it looks like on safari compared to windows?

Comment: this is on android
https://ibb.co/ypLSdFX
this is on ios
https://ibb.co/QvtCy76